# Dynamic Ports with Docker and Oracle CQN

Tags: node.js, docker, oracle11g, socket.io

I have a Dockerized node app that creates a CQN subscription in an Oracle 11g database on another machine. It gives Oracle a callback and listens on port 3033... all is well.

I see my subscription on the database:

```
SELECT REGID, REGFLAGS, CALLBACK FROM USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS;
```

[image]

When the subscription is registered, it's assigned a randomly available port, in this case 18837. Unfortunately, my Docker container is not listening for 18837 and so Oracle cannot reach my container. No problem I'll just manually specify which port to use and tell Docker to start on port 12345.

```
  await conn.subscribe('mysub', {
    callback: myCallback,
    sql:      "SELECT * FROM kpi_measurement", // the table to watch
    timeout: 0
    port: 12345
  });
```

Unfortunately. this is met with an "ORA-24911: Cannot start listener thread at specified port." I've even tried specifying ports that I know were previously used like 18837. Any port I use bombs out. Also, I'm not sure if I want to start hardcoding ports on the database side since I'm not guaranteed they'll be available in production.

I suppose one solution would be to expose my Docker container to a range of ports, but I've seen this thing choose a wide range.

Another solution would be to break my container into two parts 1) The CQN subscription registration piece and 2) a helper that runs a SELECT to get the dynamic port and then starts the docker callback code with that dynamic port. That's really frustrating considering this works nicely outside of Docker.

Comment: It works outside of Docker because you're being more liberal with your host's ports ("a wide range") than you are with the container image. If you're willing to let your host present the range of ports, there's little difference with permitting a container running on that host to accept the same range. One way to effect this for the container is to `--net=host` which directly presents the host's networking to the container's. You don't need to `--publish` ports and the container can then use the port defined by Oracle's service.

Comment: Adding --net=host didn't seem to work. I guess I should've specified this all worked on my local machine outside of docker. It doesn't work on test server (CentOS) with docker.

Comment: Hmmm :-) Perhaps I'm missing something in your configuration. It should work! I have a container (an httpd) and it assigns itself a random port on startup. I grab that port and, because the container is `--net=host`, I can curl whatever port it's configured to use. Your container would run with `--net=host` similarly and, whatever port your Node.JS process is configured to use, should be accessible from outside the container (by the host) and from a remote machine (as long as the host is accessible).

Comment: To test, I ran `iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT` to open up all ports and my app is now working using `--net=host`. I guess I don't understand why I have to do that to open up the Oracle CQN ports, I guess Docker Expose 3033 puts it in iptables? I have some Unix firewalling to learn. I also need to find which ports Oracle CQN uses and just expose those. Feel free to put your post as an answer and I'll give it the thumbs up. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works outside of Docker because you're being more liberal with your host's ports ("a wide range") than you are with the container image.

If you're willing to let your host present the range of ports, there's little difference with permitting a container running on that host to accept the same range.

One way to effect this for the container is to `--net=host` which directly presents the host's networking to the container's. You don't need to `--publish` ports and the container can then use the port defined by Oracle's service.

Comment: Just to document, I ended up doing this: 
`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=30000-49999/tcp --permanent`
`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3033/tcp --permanent`
`sudo firewall-cmd --reload`
`docker run --name <container> -d --network host -p 3033:3033 -e ENV=test <registry>/<container>`

Previously I tried doing `-p 30000:49999` and that was a big mistake. Docker adds several lines for each port in iptables. It ended up crashing docker and I had to do some magic it get it back online.